How can I generate a .xlsx file from a batch file using sqlcmd?
I have a sql script that my batch file is executing, and I'm generating a .csv file with the >> syntax.  When I switch the .csv to .xlsx, then the file doesn't place the distinct data elements into separate columns.
Is there a way to convert a .csv file to a .xlsx file, or create a .xlsx file after running a sql script?
I tried switching .csv to .xlsx but it didn't format the file correctly, all the data went into the first column.

You need Excel for that. Merely renaming it won’t do anything.

Excel 2016 is installed on my server.

csv is flat text file. xlsx is a zipped directory containing 12 or more complex xml files respecting OOXML standard (Office OpenXML format). so you cannot just change the file name. Your sql script would have to generate the binary utf-8 encoded zip file or you can use openrowset t-sql function to write a simple xlsx file , or. you can have ssis or ssrs to export to xlsx. or you can generate an excel xml spreadsheet= only one xml file with data+style that Excel can directly open up
